# How to read a file with PHP from the home directory (CentOS 7, Apache 2.4, SELinux)

Tags: php, apache, selinux, apache2.4, centos7

i want to read some file from a home directory where i get pushed files from other servers i can trust.
My index.php is in `/var/www/html/index.php`
The file i want to read via php file_get_contents is located in `/home/user123/subdir/info.txt`

The error i am getting:
`file_get_contents(/home/user123/subdir/info.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied (2)`

`aureport --avc` shows the denial error
`05.09.2014 14:17:16 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 6 dir getattr unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 denied 53606`

What i tried so far (no success):

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /home/user123/*`
`chcon -R -t httpd_user_content_t /home/user123/*`

adding the directory to the apache userdir config (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf`)

```
<Directory "/home/user123/*">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What am i missing / what am i doing wrong?

Infos for the System:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
PHP version 5.4.16
SELinux enforcing
CentOS 7
```

**UPDATE**
grant apache permission to read homedir solved the denial error from selinux
`setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on`

But the `file_get_contents(/home/user123/subdir/info.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied (2)`  is stil there...

Comment: Do you have at least `701` on `/home/user123`?  The apache user needs to be able to traverse into it to list contents.  `chmod o+x /home/user123` (then of course `o+r` on the target file)

Comment: (and +1 for solving your SELinux issue without just `setenforce 0`)  It shouldn't be necessary to set `httpd_user_content_t` on everything in `/home/user123` as you have done, and that might actually cause other problems. Instead you can just set it on the directory apache will actually read `chcon -R -t httpd_user_content_t /home/user123/subdir`  I use this approach.  To get back the old context on the home directory just `restorecon -R /home/user123` before setting `httpd_user_content_t`.

Comment: Note finally that although setting that context before `httpd_enable_homedirs` didn't appear to do anything, I believe it _is_ actually necessary in addition to `httpd_enable_homedirs`.

Comment: The home-directory itself has `701` permissions.  
The txt-file does have read permissions for all.  
Setting again the `httpd_user_content_t` permission worked. If you add your solution as answer is will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Check your open_basedir configuration which is in php.ini  - you can also look into php error log if the basedir directive is blocking the access - if so it logs something about denial of access.

Comment: @baam Ok, I summed it up below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work correctly with SELinux enforcing, several things need to be properly aligned.

First, the home directory needs to be traversable by users other than the owner. Typically home directories are `700` but the `apache` user needs execute:

```
chmod o+x /home/user123
```

Likewise, the directory inside it where the target file and the file itself need to be readable, and the directory executable (traversable):

```
chmod o+x /home/user123/subdir
chmod -R o+r /home/user123/subdir
```

As you found, you need to set the SELinux boolean to allow homedirs (`-P` to persist on reboot)

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
```

Finally, the target directory needs the correct SELinux context. For a read-only directory, `httpd_user_content_t` is probably most appropriate.

```
chcon -R -t httpd_user_content_t /home/user123/subdir
```

**Important to note**: Only the directory Apache needs to read should have its SELinux context changed. It isn't necessary to change the context of the home directory itself `/home/user123`, and doing so would likely have detrimental effects on other things (maybe even on your ability to login!)